# Is the following Mean Error plot while training machine using MATLAB acceptable?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, machine-learning

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12eKg.png)

The error is shooting up near 25000th iteration but the learning rate adjusts after that, reducing the error and bringing it down to a fairly constant value till 35000th iteration.

Comment: Some kind of description would be nice. Is this the training error? And if it is why would you care for it and not for the validation/test error. What kind of model are you using? What kind of accuracy do you want to archive on that problem? What kind of problem are you working on? Without an answer to those basic questions it is hard to tell you if that error is good or not. Anyways the error function normally goes exponentally downwards and it looks kinda wrong, but if it produces the output you desire, why would you change it?

Comment: Yes this is the training error on Quaternion Dataset of 21 point-cloud. The result is good but not completely efficient. And I feel if that bit of error(of exponential increase) vanishes, the result will be better.